# RestKit & Parse: mapping a relationship for RKObjectManager putObject operation

Tags: core-data, parse-platform, restkit

I'm attempting to map the inverse relationship for the RKEntityMapping of my ManagedObjects, but I'm having some difficulty getting things to work. I'm exchanging data with Parse.com and I am able to perform my GET requests without issue as well as mapping the results into Core Data. The problem arises when I attempt to perform a putObject operation that contains a relationship to another object.

Per the Parse.com documentation: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-updating, the request needs to look similar to the following:

'{"opponents":{"__op":"AddRelation","objects":[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"EquipmentType","objectId":"Vx4nudeWn"}]}}'

I've subclassed RKObjectManager to encapsulate all of my mappings as follows:

```
_entityMapping = [self createMappingForEntity:[EquipmentState class]];

[self addResponseDescriptor:_entityMapping withPathPattern:[EquipmentState pathPattern]];

[self addRequestDescriptor:[_entityMapping inverseMapping] class:[EquipmentState class] rootKeyPath:nil];}

[_entityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"type" toKeyPath:@"type" withMapping:[EquipmentTypeManager sharedManager].entityMapping]];
```

I am mapping my EquipmentState class, which has a relationship to EquipmentType. When I perform my GET request, RestKit is able to successfully map the objects without issue. However the same cannot be said when I perform a PUT. Clearly this is an issue with my mapping but I don't know how I can define a mapping that will produce similar output to the above.

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Have you thought about creating an object representing the relationship data required by parse and using that?

Comment: I'd like to do that but I have been unable to locate an example of how to do that in the RestKit documentation.